# Generate dynamic hyperlink based on querystring

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wanna generate Hyperlink based on query string .Let me explain it more

Topics clicked rite now:(here I want my hyperlinks)....,....

1.Cat1

2.Cat2

3.Cat3

when i click cat1 it generate querystring: ?Cat=Cat1

when I click on cat2 it will generate querystring ?Cat=Cat2

so based on that I want to create hyperlink whose
text is query string(value)

and url is url-(name and value of that query string)lets say for cat1

if currently url is http://www.google.com/?Cat=Cat1&subcat=subcat1
so text should be cat1(and its url should be www.google.com/?subcat=subcat1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to take a look at the [jquery.query plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/query-object).  In particular the `get` function which returns an array of tokens that you can iterate over.

Something like this should get you started:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/files/jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.query.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
    $.each($.query.get(), function(val, prop) {
        $('.menu').append($('<a />').attr('href', $.query.empty().set(val, prop).toString()).text(val));
        $('.menu').append($('<br />'));
    });
});

</script>
</head>
<body>
   <div class="menu">
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

i would say that probably the way to go for this is the following (syntax isnt correct most likely)

I believe this is some regular string manipulation..

```
var cat1 = "topic1";
var cat2 = "topic2";
var subcat1 = "subtopic1"; etc
url = "http://google.com/?cat=" + cat1 + "&subcat=" + subcat1
<a href=url/>CAT 1 Link<a>
```

i hope this helps

Comment: Thanks Erika for replying but the thing is query string is not fixed. May be it will be one query string,two or three.I want to get the value of that query string and display it thats pretty simple but I want the url to be current url-(query string which is clicked)